# How to add custom classes inside link with wordpress editor link button

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am creating a link of pdf with 2 option 1st view pdf file using fancybox and 2nd option for download pdf file. So there i have to add fancybox class for view add no-fancybox for download

I have added this code as custom but i dont want to add manualy

```
<ul class="literatures-media">
    <li><a class="fancybox iframe btn-primary fa fa-eye" href="http://joeee/emp/ashish/live/mmvv/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/pdfdocument.pdf"></a> </li>
    <li> <a class="btn-primary fa fa-download nofancybox" href="http://joeee/emp/ashish/live/mmvv/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/pdfdocument.pdf" target="_blank"></a></li>
</ul>
```

So please help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add class dynamically using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".literatures-media li").first().addClass("fancybox");
$(".literatures-media li").last().addClass("nofancybox");
});
```